# Adding methods to existing chart and series class c#

Tags: c#, class, charts, delegates, wrapper

[image]

Hi, everyone.I am developing a plotting library using windows form of c#, and I would like to ask how do you add my own methods to the classes like chart and series independently without cutting the connection between them?

Don't worry about the rope, it's just something I thought  physical to represent the connection between chart and series as series is under chart.

I tried to use inheritance , and add new methods but then I realised it wouldn't work because when you replace Chart by e.g.public class Mychart : Chart , Mychart won't communicate with chart.Series., as you can see from the drawing, the object inherited from Chart has no connection with Series( i.e. no connection between them ) , This is the simplified version of the huge problem I encountered in my project. I hugely appreciate any help or attempt.

To clarify what I mean by no connection:

```
this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
```

you can see the chart1 was generated by Chart class right?

OK Now go ahead and replace chart by Mychart ( with new methods )

```
this.chart2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Mychart();
```

But the problem comes when you try to generate series from Mychart.

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
```

you couldn't do inheritance again for series, because now as you can see Series is under Chart not under Mychart, they have no connection at all

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Mychart.NewSeries series2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Mychart.NewSeries();
```

New Series doesn't exist at all <-- the last code I made it wrong deliberately to show you what's wrong with inheritance.

at the end of the day this is how I could call my function, so you know why the connection (rope) is hugely important .

```
        private delegate int PlotXYDelegate(double x, double y); // define a function pointer 

        private void PlotXYAppend(Chart chart, Series dataSeries, double x, double y)
        {
            chart.Invoke(new PlotXYDelegate(dataSeries.Points.AddXY), new Object[] { x, y });
        }
```

the above defines a function which takes a chart, a series , and I pass in a pair of points every time.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking about. Your diagram is good, but it is not the UML or any other notation I know and it doesn't exactly clarifies your system or problems. Try to present some basic snippets of your code and describe what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I clarified the question just now, hope it might makes it more obvious. This question is more specific to c sharp win form user

Comment: Is adding methods directly to Chart/Series off limits? I don't quite understand the "Rope" concept. What is it exactly? Some another class or just modelled relation between Chart and Series (by sound of it, most likely composition)?

Comment: because Series is a class under Chart, that's why I said they have a connection. If you go ahead and build a new class inherit from Chart, the Mynewchart.series is different from chart.series. there is no rope ... Rope is just something i made up to make it easy to visualise.

Comment: If you are subclassing the Chart then it will be able to consume the original Series that are defined inside his parent class.

Comment: @Eugene Podskal Are you sure? do you mean they still have connection?

Answer (score 0):

**ABOUT INHERITANCE :**

You are using the [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

It has [Chart.Series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.series%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of type [SeriesCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This collection has method [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts the [Series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances. But it doesn't mean that it will accept only the Series instances - it will also accept anything that is derived from the Series class.

So, for example you have created your own inheritors of Chart and Series with custom methods:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...

public class MyChart: Chart
{
    public void MyChartMethod() { }
}

public class MySeries : Series
{
    public MySeries(String name) : base(name)
    {

    }

    public void MySeriesMethod() { }
}
```

Then you can use them in the same way you use the classic Chart and Series classes interchangeably:

```
    // Classic chart
    Chart chart = new Chart();

    chart.Series.Add(new Series("Classic series instance for Chart"));
    chart.Series.Add(new MySeries("My series instance for Chart"));

    this.Controls.Add(chart);

    // MyChart
    MyChart myChart = new MyChart();

    chart.Series.Add(new Series("Classic series instance for MyChart"));
    chart.Series.Add(new MySeries("My series instance for MyChart"));

    this.Controls.Add(myChart );
    ...
    myChart.MyChartMethod()
```

The only problem you can encounter is that the SeriesCollection stores its Series as Series references, so in your methods you will have to cast the Series you use:

```
public class MyChart: Chart
{
    public void MyMethod() 
    {
        MySeries mySeries = (MySeries)this.Series[0];
        mySeries.MySeriesMethod();
    }
}
```

It is not the best solution and can potentially bring some problems if you will ever decide to mix your MySeries and original Series.

**ABOUT WRAPPERS :**

Wrappers do not mean inheritance. They are used when inheritance is not an option - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern. Usually it is something like:

```
public class Original
{
    public void DoOriginal() { }
}

public class OriginalWrapper
{
    private Original original;
    public OriginalWrapper(Original original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public void DoOriginal() { original.DoOriginal();}

    public void DoOriginalWrapper() { }
}
```

OriginalWrapper will be able to do all the things the Original can + new function DoOriginalWrapper(). But it is not inherited from Original so you won't be able to use in place of the Original instances:

```
public class ConsumerOfOriginal
{
    public void ConsumeOriginal(Original original);
}

Original original = new Original();
OriginalWrapper originalWrapper = new OriginalWrapper(original);

Consumer consumer = new ConsumerOfOriginal();

consumer.ConsumeOriginal(original); // Compiles and works
consumer.ConsumeOriginal(originalWrapper); // Fails to compile
```

To overcome this problem you will have to either unwrap the wrapped instance or use interfaces as parameters of your methods.

**SOLUTION TO YOUR PROBLEM :**

I don't know your exact scenarios, so I can't recommend you inheritance over the composition(wrapping), but I hope that my post cleared at least some things for you.

**P.S.:** I'd recommended you to read:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618/OOP-and-UML

They may be a bit too complex and contain a lot of info irrelevant for now , but in the end they will at least outline and show many concepts useful in programming and OOP design. Good luck.